# My (AT&T) assembly (x86-x64) code should increment but doesn't

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm trying to make a small program in assembly (for AT&T). I'm trying to get an input from the user in the form of an integer, increment it after that and then output the incremented value. However, the value doesn't increment. I've spent the last hours trying everything I could come up with, but it still doesn't work, so I have the idea that I maybe understand a concept in assembly not well, causing me to not spot the mistake. This is my code:

```
1 hiString: .asciz "Hi\n"
  2 formatstr: .asciz "%ld"
  3 
  4 .global main
  5 
  6 main:
  7     movq $0, %rax           #no vector registers printf
  8     movq $hiString, %rdi    #load hiString
  9     call printf             #printf
 10     call inout              #inout
 11     movq $0, %rdi           #loading exit value into register rdi
 12     call exit               #exit
 13 
 14 inout:
 15     pushq %rbp              #Pushing bp
 16     movq %rsp, %rbp         #Moving sp to bp
 17     subq $8, %rsp           #Space on stack for variable
 18     leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
 19     movq $formatstr, %rdi   #1st argument scanf
 20     movq $0, %rax           #no vector for scanf registers
 21     call scanf              #scanf
 22     incq %rsi
 23     call printf
```

From a tutorial I got of a friend of mine, I learned that lines 17 to 19 are necessary, however, I think I don't use the stack space I adress there, so I suspect the error having something with that. I'm not sure ofcourse. Thank you in advance.

EDIT, UPDATED CODE (printf is still called in the subroutine now)

```
    1 hiString: .asciz "hi\n"
  2 formatstr: .asciz "%ld"
  3 
  4 .global main
  5 
  6 main:
  7     movq $0, %rax          
  8     movq $hiString, %di   
  9     call printf             
 10     call inout              
 11     movq $0, %rdi           
 12     call exit               
 13 
 14 inout:
 15     pushq %rbp             
 16     movq %rsp, %rbp         
 17     subq $8, %rsp         
 18     leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
 19     movq $formatstr, %rdi   
 20     movq $0, %rax           
 21     call scanf              
 22     popq %rax
 23     incq %rax
 24     movq %rax, %rsi
 25     movq $0, %rax
 26     call printf
 27     addq $8, %rs
```

It runs and increments now, however, when the incremented value is outputed, there show up some weird signs after the value.

Edit: Nevermind, the above only happened once, now there is no incremented value outputted, only weird signs.

Comment: Your last edit removed the `ret` from the end of `inout` again....

Answer (score 1):

This is an assembly-level version of the classic confusion about how to call `scanf` correctly.

```
 14 inout:
 15     pushq %rbp              #Pushing bp
 16     movq %rsp, %rbp         #Moving sp to bp
 17     subq $8, %rsp           #Space on stack for variable
 18     leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
 19     movq $formatstr, %rdi   #1st argument scanf
 20     movq $0, %rax           #no vector for scanf registers
 21     call scanf              #scanf
```

(Editor's note: prefer either `mov $formatstr, %edi` in a Linux non-PIE executable, or more portably position-independent `lea formatstr(%rip), %rdi` to put the address of a string in static storage into a register).

Up to this point your code is correct (except that you haven't aligned the stack correctly, but don't worry about that right now, `scanf` will probably let you get away with it).  Update: modern builds of glibc do have [a scanf that faults on a misaligned RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r), since Ubuntu 18.04 for example, maybe earlier.

```
 22     incq %rsi
```

Here's where you go wrong.  Before the call you set RSI (the second argument register for `scanf`) to be a *pointer* to a storage location.  `scanf` read a number from stdin and wrote it *to that storage location*, not to RSI.

From the discussion in the comments, your intention is to add one to the value read by `scanf` and immediately print it back out.  As several other people pointed out, after `scanf` returns, you cannot assume that the values you loaded into RSI, RDI, or RAX are intact.  (The [x86-64 psABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) specifies which registers are to be preserved over a function call: of the integer registers, only RBX, RBP, and R12 through R15 are preserved.  You should read this document cover to cover if you intend to do much assembly programming on x86-64.  (Caution: Windows uses a different ABI whose calling convention is documented on MSDN, see links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).))

So you must set up the args to `printf` from scratch because `scanf` destroyed those registers:

```
       movq -8(%rbp), %rsi   # load variable as arg 2 of printf
       incq %rsi             # and add one
       movq $formatstr, %rdi # first argument to printf
       xorl %rax, %rax       # no vector args to printf
       call printf
```

Pay close attention to the difference between `scanf` and `printf` here: you can use the same format string for both, but when you call `scanf` you pass the *address of a storage location* (`leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi`), whereas when you call `printf` you pass the *value to be printed* (`movq -8(%rbp), %rsi; incq %rsi`).

(In fact you *ought* to use a slightly different format string when you call `printf`, because you need to print a newline after the number, so `"%ld\n"` would be better.)

Your current code does *almost* this, in a different way.  I do it this way because it's bad practice to mess with the stack pointer (`popq %rax`) in the middle of a function.  (Remember what I said about not aligning the stack correctly?  It's much easier to keep the stack aligned if you set up a complete "call frame" on entry and then leave the stack pointer alone until exit.  Technically you are only *required* to have the stack pointer aligned at the point of each call instruction, though.)

You also don't end the function correctly:

```
 27     addq $8, %rs
```

I think you didn't copy and paste your entire program - this looks like it's been cut off in the middle of the line.  Regardless, if you're going to bother having a frame pointer in the first place (frame pointers are not required on x86-64) you should use it again to exit:

```
        movq %rbp, %rsp
        popq %rbp
        ret
```

Incidentally, "AT&T" assembly syntax is used for many different CPU architectures.  When talking about assembly language we always need to know the CPU architecture *first*; the syntax variant (if any) is secondary.  You should have titled the question "My assembly program (x86-64, AT&T syntax) ..."

---

As a final piece of advice, I would suggest you compile this C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void inout(void)
{
    long x;
    scanf("%ld", &x);
    printf("%ld\n", x+1);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("hi\n");
    inout();
    return 0;
}
```

with your choice of C compiler, using options equivalent to `-S -O2 -fno-inline` (that is: generate textual assembly language, optimized, but don't do any inlining) and then read through the assembly output line by line.  Whenever the C compiler does something different than you did, that probably means it knows something you don't know and you should learn about that something.

Or more simply, [**look at it on the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+use++-fpie++for+RIP-relative+LEA+for+format+strings%0A//+Godbolt+default+is+-fno-pie,+unlike+most+Linux+distros%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Astatic+void+inout(void)%0A%7B%0A++++long+x%3B%0A++++scanf(%22%25ld%22,+%26x)%3B%0A++++printf(%22%25ld%5Cn%22,+x%2B1)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22hi%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++inout()%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:42.09656637906497,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171'),(name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-fno-inline',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:57.90343362093502,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the overall feedback, however, I think I still need some more pointers. I actually tried out the code you provided, however, I still don't get the right output. (When I keep call printf in my inout subroutine, I still get the non incremented input and when I remove printf there, and call it in my main routine (after moving the content of rax into rsi), I get no output at all. So, I still don't understand something I think.

Comment: OP should further note that functions are allowed to (and generally do) destroy the arguments they received upon return. It is highly unlikely that `rsi` contains the value you originally placed there on return from `scanf`.

Comment: @RomeeB Please show us your updated code. Do not remove the original code from the question, just stick the updated code below.

Comment: @RomeeB I don't see your call to `printf`. Where is it?

Comment: @fuz, excuse me, I uploaded the wrong code, it is edited now. Now the value is incremented and shown, however, there are some weird signs after the new value.

Comment: @fuz nevermind, the above only happened once, now there is no incremented value outputted, only weird signs.

Comment: @RomeeB Again, you make the mistake I already pointed out: `scanf` is allowed to destroy the contents of all argument registers. You have to set up all arguments anew. Instead, your code somehow expects `scanf` to preserve the arguments you set up which isn't the case. You should really look up the calling convention of your platform when programming in assembly.

Comment: @fuz Many thanks! I obviously forgot to load formatstr again into printf, as you already tried to point out. Again, thanks for your time and help, you tips will probably help me out more than once.

Comment: @RomeeB You need to load all arguments to `printf` again, including `rsi`, which probably has been trashed by `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

re: updated code:

> It runs and increments now, however, when the incremented value is outputed, there show up some weird signs after the value.

Arg-passing registers are call-clobbered.  You call `printf` without putting the format-string into `%rdi`, which you have to assume holds garbage after `scanf` returns.

Single-step your code with a debugger.  Use `ni` to step over `call`s in gdb.  (See the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for GDB tips).